# Understanding stochastic Big-$O$ notation in a stochastic process context

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, asymptotics, probability-limit-theorems

I am trying to understand an equality in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.4174v2) about *locally stationary processes* on page 24.

The equality includes stochastic Big-O (see D5 in [this paper](http://www2.math.uu.se/~svante/papers/sjN6.pdf) for a definition of stochastic O-notation) and is as follows:

$$
\sum_{j = 0}^T \left[\prod_{k=0}^{j-1} \alpha\left(\frac{t-k}{T}\right)\right]\varepsilon_{t-j} =
\sum_{j = 0}^T \alpha\left(\frac{1}{T}\right)^j \varepsilon_{t-j} + O_p\left(\frac{1}{T}\right),
$$
for $T \rightarrow \infty$ where $\varepsilon_{t-j}$ is white noise. (I have left some coefficients from the paper out and I have only considered finitely many summands here for simplicity)

---

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3666397/proving-prod-k-0n-f-left-fract-kt-right-ft-tn-o1-t-and-better) I have already proved that 
$$
 \prod_{k=0}^{j-1} \alpha\left(\frac{t-k}{T}\right) = \alpha\left(\frac{1}{T}\right)^j + O\left(\frac{1}{T}\right)
$$
with deterministic Big-O notation.

However, if I plug this result into the equation above, I get

### \begin{align*}
 \sum_{j = 0}^T \left[\prod_{k=0}^{j-1} \alpha\left(\frac{t-k}{T}\right)\right]\varepsilon_{t-j} 
 &= \sum_{j = 0}^T \left[\alpha\left(\frac{1}{T}\right)^j + O\left(\frac{1}{T}\right)\right]\varepsilon_{t-j} \\
 &= \sum_{j = 0}^T \alpha\left(\frac{1}{T}\right)^j \varepsilon_{t-j} + \sum_{j = 0}^T O\left(\frac{1}{T}\right) \varepsilon_{t-j}.
\end{align*}

Now we would need the following:

### $$ \sum_{j = 0}^T O\left(\frac{1}{T}\right) \varepsilon_{t-j} = O_p\left(\frac{1}{T}\right)$$

It is easy to see that $O\left(\frac{1}{T}\right) \varepsilon_{t-j} =  O_p\left(\frac{1}{T}\right)$, but summing up I would get
$$ \sum_{j = 0}^T O\left(\frac{1}{T}\right) \varepsilon_{t-j} = \sum_{j = 0}^T O_p\left(\frac{1}{T}\right) = T  O_p\left(\frac{1}{T}\right) = O_p(1)$$
and not the result above.